# How filter Apex Class View on code coverage?

Tags: custom-view, code-coverage

In the Apex Classes page, how can I create a view that filters on code coverage ? Code coverage is one of the fields selectable so I figured I could do just do:

```
Code coverage -  less then -  90
```

But this is not working, the view still contains classes with 100% test coverage. What value can I use ?

**Update:**
I combine this with a namespace filter to filter out package apex

```
Namespace Prefix  - equals  -  (blank)
```

Filter logic  `1 AND 2`

Neither 90 or 90% give a different result, nor should the namespace filter have any impact, the code coverage filter appears to not be applied, whereas the namespace filter is applied.

**Observation:**

- Both "Greater Than" and "Greater of equal" will work as expected, but both "Less than" and "Less or equal" do not.
- While either of the "less" can be negated with NOT and work, using NOT on either of the "Greater" operators will not work and display all classes.

Is this is a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Aren't percentages expressed in terms of a float between `0.0` and `1.0`?

Comment: I've tried, for code coverage this is not working and will only show you the 0% ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. When I used it I had the % sign in my value, but looking at this again it works even without it.
Here is an example that works for me.
[image: Example of working filter]

Can you post your full filter? Are you perhaps using filter logic with multiple conditions?

EDIT--
So looking at this again in light of what you've said, it looks like the less filter fails specifically on the case of classes with 100% coverage. I tried progressively lowering the value in the filter and it seems to work against values less than 100 but not 100%. So <90% gives you <90% + everything with 100%. Looks like a bug to me!

[image: Filtered on coverage less than 40%]

Here are my results for "<40% coverage"...

Comment: I guess they are performing an alphabetical comparisment and not a numerical. I've added a "does not contain 100" filter clause which seems to do the trick.

Comment: Yes! That's it. I just tried filtering on code coverage <4 and got results from 39% down. So it is an alpha comparison.